# jarvis ai building in python for windows

Tags: python, windows-10

from gtts import gTTS
import os
import speech_recognition as sr
import webbrowser
import time

def talkToME(audioString):
    print(audioString)
    tts=gTTS(text=audioString, lang='en')
    tts.save('audio.mp3')
    os.system('mpg123 audio.mp3')

## listens for commands

```
def myCommand():

    r = sr.Recognizer()

    with sr.Microphone as source:
        print('Say Something!')
        r.pause_threshold = 1
        r.adjust_for_ambient_noise(source, duration =1)
        audio = r.listen(source)


    try:
        command = r.recognise_google(audio)
        print('you said: ' + command+ '/n')

        #loop back to continue listen for commands

    except sr.UnknownvalueError:
        assistant(myCommand())

        return command
#if statements for executing commands

    def assistant(command):

        if "how are you" in command:
            talkToMe("i am fine")


time.sleep(2)
talkToMe(' hi brian, what can i do for you?')

while True:
    command = recordAudio()
    assistant(myCommand())
```

this is my code. however, when i run it there is no error message and nothing seems to happen. i am kind of lost whats wrong. it was supposed to answer "I am fine" but nothing happens. i am using windows 10. and python 3.6.3 
the code seems to be for linux. but i dont know why? and even if so how can edit or write a code for creating a simple jarvis for windows using python.
thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing the following lines to get results:

`sr.Microphone` to `sr.Microphone()` and
`r.recognise_google(audio)` to `r.recognize_google(audio)`

Please tell me if this works cause it worked for me.

Comment: thanks for your help, really appreciate it! sorry for the delay, i never thought someone would really reply cause this was my first time.